# change transparent image color dynamically

Tags: php, image-processing, gdlib

i have to change image color dynamically using php i used the following code

```
$imgname = "source.png";
$im = imagecreatefrompng ($imgname);
if($im && imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 27, 133, 85))
{
    echo 'Image successfully shaded as per color.';

    imagepng($im, 'Result.png');
    imagedestroy($im);
}
else
{
    echo 'Image create succesfully.';
}
```

but when i used it with transparent image it show me large thing border

can we resolve using the GD Lib or image stick any function ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are talking about quality issue or shadow issue then I can be resolve by using `imagesavealpha` function before applying filter.

code should be

```
<?php
$imgname = "source.png";
$im = imagecreatefrompng ($imgname);
imagesavealpha($im, true);  
if($im && imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 27, 133, 85))
{
    echo 'Image successfully shaded as per color.';

    imagepng($im, 'Result.png');
    imagedestroy($im);
}
else
{
    echo 'Image create succesfully.';
}
?>
```

Comment: when i use imagefilter and pass a color then color is changed but in resulting image color is not what i passed. any suggestion?

Comment: It would be great if you share image used in operation and image color.